# Removing duplicate rows from search results in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Using Notepad++ V6.9.2
When searching for a string in text file and string appear twice on same line the same line appear twice on the Find results.
Is there a way to remove duplicate lines from the results ?

For example if I have this text file

```
  USA    Italy    USA
```

And then I search for the string USA I expect to get single line in the find result and not two lines which are the same.
I get single line when using EditPlus tool and I would expect to get the same also in NotePad++ without the need to use Regular Expression which not every one knows.

Comment: Why not use regular expressions? This is the kind of problem that Regex solves

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The "Find in files" command shows each match on a separate line in the  "Find results". (Just tested in Notepad++ 6.9.2; but has been the same in every previous version I can remember).

Comment: @Daniel Regular expressions could be used, but the "Find results" will have the whole match highlighted, not just the wanted words. In a line like `abcdefabcdefabc` it would be nice to have the searches for `def` reported as `Line nnn:  abc<em def>abc<em def>abc` and not as `Line nnn:  abc<em defabcdef>abc` or `Line nnn:  abc<em defabcdefabc>`.

Comment: Dont just search for USA, search for "USA " (a space) or for "USA\t" (a tab), available if search-mode is set to extended. Naturally, either "USA\n" or "USA\r" would work too, to find the last one on the line.

Comment: enhzflep - the "USA    Italy    USA" was just an example I don't know where in the line the text will be and if there are spaces, tabs, other characters before or after.

Answer (score 0):

Use regex to find a text and wrap all the line:

```
^.*USA.*$
```